# How to return fusedLocationProviderClient().lastLocation as flow from a function in kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi, kotlin-coroutines, kotlinx.coroutines.flow

## What i am doing

So i am developing a weather forecast application in which i am accessing the device location using fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation and most of us knows that the location provider return a task, so for that i am using coroutines Deferred so that whenever the task got completed it gives me the device location
please have a look upon the code for better understanding

```
private fun getLastDeviceLocation(): Deferred<Location?> {
        return if (hasLocationPermission())
            fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.asDeferred()
        else
            throw LocationPermissionNotGrantedException()
    }
```

## What my problem is

but now i want my location to be a live location so for that i have to use coroutines flow, so that whenever my location changes i'll be able to fetch weather for the new location automatically, but because i am new to kotlin coroutines i am not sure how to achieve that and how i can be able to use flow with deferred,

can anyone please help me out or if this is not feasible do suggest me some other work aroung to achieve my goal
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 7):

If you want to convert `Deferred` to `Flow`:

```
val lastLocationFlow: Flow<Location> = flow {
    emit(fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.asDeferred().await())
}
```

[`flow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flow.html) is the most basic flow builder. It takes a suspendable block as a parameter, that's responsible for emitting values. [`Deferred.await()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-deferred/await.html) will suspend execution until the task returns a `Location` (or `null`). The flow will then emit the value and finish.

---

If you want to convert [`requestLocationUpdates`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback,%20android.os.Looper)) from callback to `Flow`, you could use [`callbackFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response @Eugen, as I m new to Coroutines can please explain how can I use callback Flow in my Case, I mean in this function

Comment: Hi, combine [`callbackFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html) with [`requestLocationUpdates`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#public-taskvoid-requestlocationupdates-locationrequest-request,-locationcallback-callback,-looper-looper). Everything you need is in the linked documentation. I leave it as an exercise for reader, it's better for learning than a readymade solution for copy-pasting.

Comment: if anyone else is still confused with this stuff I think you should checkout my latest blog post on the same
https://medium.com/@m.s.siddique131/modern-ways-of-developing-location-based-android-apps-using-callbackflows-coroutines-1ef18999027b